# Не работает клик по области python 3 Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

Использую код  по типу

```
click1=driver.find_element_by_class_name('имя класса')
Click1.click()
```

При этом send_keys работают нормально. Как это можно исправить?

Comment: В `click1` находится валидный элемент, в который можно вводить текст, но при этому не работает клик? Приведите, пожалуйста, в вопросе [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Зачем вам пример, когда синтаксис правильный? Он не работает на определенном сайте, хотя тот не отличается сильно по структуре. У себя в коде я указал точно такие же строки, только класс поставил нужный себе.

Comment: А зачем вы выложили стандартный пример получения элемента и клику по нему? `Он не работает на определенном сайте`, вот минимальный пример и покажет что за сайт и как повторить эту проблему :)